# Ansible reboot remote host wait for 60 sec and reboot next remote host

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to reboot remote host with ansible. For now it working but remote host rebooted in the same times. I would like to reboot one by one with sleep time.

I tried to put wait_for in the code below but It doesn't work. I got error that conflict with shell.

```
  Playbook file
  - name: Rebooting ...
    wait_for:
      time_out: 60
    shell: sleep 2 && /sbin/shutdown -r now "Reboot required"
    async: 1
    poll: 0
    ignore_errors: true
    register: rebooting
```

```
Error message:
The error appears to have been in '/home/ansible/reboot-hosts.yml': line 20, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


  - name: Rebooting ...
    ^ here

exception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleParserError'>
exception: conflicting action statements: shell, wait_for

The error appears to have been in '/home/ansible/reboot-hosts.yml': line 20, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
```

This is expect procedure:

- Reboot host 1
- Sleep 60 seconds
- Reboot host 2
- Sleep 60 seconds
- Reboot host 3

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57679745/edit) your question and include the `wait_for` code you tried as well as the error? It sounds like `wait_for` is what you need, so I'm curious what you've already tried.

Comment: Already added. Thanks Peschke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Peschke said, try the [reboot](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/reboot_module.html) module.  But do do it one at a time, you need to set `serial: 1` in the play:

```
- hosts: all
  serial: 1
  become: yes

  tasks:
  - name: Rebooting ...
    reboot:
      reboot_timeout: 60
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have two actions in your task: `wait_for` and `shell`. Unless you use a [block](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html), the [`wait_for`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html) module needs to be within its own task.

Try something like this:

```
  - name: Rebooting ...
    shell: sleep 2 && /sbin/shutdown -r now "Reboot required"
    async: 1
    poll: 0
    ignore_errors: true
    register: rebooting

  - name: wait for reboot
    wait_for:
      timeout: 60
    delegate_to: localhost
```

---

Another option is to use the [`reboot`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/reboot_module.html) module. This module will wait for the system to go down and come back up before proceeding. By default, it waits 600 seconds for the system to come back up.

If you only wanted to wait 60 seconds, you could do the following:

```
  - name: Rebooting ...
    reboot:
      reboot_timeout: 60
```